# Remove space before and after string in array and keep structure

Tags: php

I need to remove all space before string and keep space in string and remove all space after string in array and keep the structure of array

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($data as $index => $value){
    $tables = json_encode($value["tables"], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    echo $tables;
}
```

Result from `echo $tables;`

```
[{"lang":"cs","lang_title":"Český","menus":[{"header":"Mechanika","rows":[{"parameter":"Hmotnost","value":"0.65kg"}]}]},{"lang":"pl","lang_title":"Polský","menus":[{"header":"Mechanika nová","rows":[{"parameter":"Masa","value":"0.65kg"}]}]},{"lang":"en","lang_title":"Anglický","menus":[{"header":" Me chanics ","rows":[{"parameter":"Weight","value":"0.65kg"}]}]}]
```

And I need to keep the structure of `$value["tables"]` and just remove spaces in `header`,`parameter`,`value`

So example `"header":" Me chanics "` -> `"header":"Me chanics"`

Comment: Iterate through all this and replace the values with their new value after "trim()".

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure if I understand, can you explain "Iterate through all this and replace the values" please? I don't know how you mean that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_walk_recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) to walk through entire array and use [trim](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to remove extra spaces

```php
    $json = '[{"lang":"cs","lang_title":"Český ","menus":[{"header":"Mechanika","rows":[{"parameter":"Hmotnost","value":"0.65kg"}]}]},{"lang":"pl","lang_title":"Polský","menus":[{"header":"Mechanika nová","rows":[{"parameter":"Masa","value":"0.65kg"}]}]},{"lang":"en","lang_title":"Anglický","menus":[{"header":" Me chanics ","rows":[{"parameter":"Weight","value":"0.65kg"}]}]}]';
    
    
    $data = json_decode($json, true);
    array_walk_recursive(
            $data, function(&$v, $key) {
        if (in_array($key, ["header", "parameter", "value"]))
            $v = trim($v);
    }
    );
    
    echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: It seems like my problem is fixed, thank you so much for your time and your willing.

Answer (score 1):

What better you can do is after decoding the data into $data use array_map function

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$data = array_map('trim', $data);
```

Like this you use instead of foreach.

or either use

```
trim(); // Function
```

Comment: Okay, thank you, can I ask how to use this function array_filter() with trim()?

Comment: @AmeliaDernigue I here said to use array_filter() or either trim(). I don't think trim will be require if you use array_filter().